# Make Kafka topics be created automatically from spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka

My Spring boot project has 4 modules and I needed to use Kafka to establish communication between the modules. I installed Kafka on my computer and created the topics using cmd.

The problem is, after I submit my project, the topics won't work unless my teacher has the same topics created on his computer (from what I understand).

Is there a way to make sure my project automatically creates the topics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `spring-kafka` dependency and add some Topic beans

```java
@Bean
public NewTopic topic() {
  return TopicBuilder.name("example")....build();
}
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#configuring-topics